# Electric oven: Bake and Broil not Working

Tags: electrical, repair, oven

isherwood: Same oven as prior question, but new issue.

In bake mode, the broil and bake elements get warm.  Neither element gets hot.  In broil mode,  neither element gets warm.
The cycle lamp is on in each mode.  The controller terminals show proper continuity across all terminals in all modes.

The oven is a Hotpoint RK38T.  The controller is model WB22X5134.  All electrical and mechanical, no electronic components

I would appreciate comments on the cause and how to fix this issue.

New data: The voltage across the thermostat terminals shows 224 volts in broil mode.  I was expecting 110 volts because line 1 is not connected to the thermostat in broil mode.

Comment: First thing to try, turn the breaker off and back on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [electric oven bake element gets warm but does not get hot](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132489/electric-oven-bake-element-gets-warm-but-does-not-get-hot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I am looking at your other post - thanks isherwood for linking , however you should have linked to it, to make it easier to read it..

You actually have a very similar issue and it could all be the same.

1: Did you check your range outlet for proper voltage. 
You should have 110V on both phases to Neutral and if so equipped to ground.

2: Your elements could be broken at the heating element connection. Generally there is a screw type connection with a nut. Sometimes they are also insulated with a compound at these connections / pass throughs. The possibility is they could be cracked or broken completely - WHEN you have the oven UNPLUGGED and off - give a slight tug on the wires attached see if anything is loosey goosey or wiggly.

What voltage do you measure across the elements in each mode ?

Comment: Ken: Oven shows 110V  to Neutral on each lead.
In bake mode, bake element shows 59V, broil element shows 51V.  In broil mode, each element shows 0V.

Comment: @paul while I have not seen the wiring diagram of the service manual - the fact you have 0v in broil mode on the broiler element (if measuring element to neutral and not across the element) I would say the wiring might not be correct (connected wrong or broke) or the controller is defective or if you have a separate relay board - the relay is bad.

Comment: Ken:  0V in broil mode is measured across the broiler element.    I found the Leg 2 wire broken off at the the broiler element.

Comment: @paul Ok so now that you have fixed your broken wire, is the oven working . Can you update with new voltage readings for each element Broil and Bake - neutral to Element Terminal 1 , Neutral to Element Terminal 2, and Terminal 1 to Terminal 2). In both Bake only and Broil Only modes.

Comment: Ken: The oven is working.  The broken wire appears to have melted at the connector.  I could not find a duplicate of the copper connector.   I replaced it with a high-temperature ring connector.  I did not measure any voltages after the repair.  In broil mode, the broiler element gets hot and the bake element stays cool.  In bake mode, the bake element gets hot and the broiler element gets warm.  The cycle lamp is on in broil and bake modes.

Comment: @Paul glad you got it fixed. Please mark this Answer as the answer by clicking the check box that is next to the two up/down arrows.