# Is CD 12R 12 gage stranded wire suitable for use in an electric oven?

Tags: electrical, repair, oven

I have a spool of CD 12R 12 gage stranded wire, Standard Motor Products, spiffy spool.

Is this wire suitable to replace the wire from L2 to the controller in an electric oven?

The oven is the one in: [Electric oven: Bake and Broil not Working](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136024/electric-oven-bake-and-broil-not-working)  and  [electric oven bake element gets warm but does not get hot](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132489/electric-oven-bake-element-gets-warm-but-does-not-get-hot).

Comment: there is an icon for adding hyperlinks .... or just paste the hyperlink address

Comment: @jsotola he may be on a Mac, the trick is when you click the address bar, don't roll down *at all* before you hit command-C to copy, otherwise you will get a bunch of suggested search keywords. (I hate that feature).  Sometimes you can also do it with "Share..." and "copy URL"...

Comment: Can you read the printing *on the wire* off to us?  Also, can you provide that printing from the wire already in the oven?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 
The wire has red insulation with no printing on the wire.  The oven wire shows
ilegibleAL ELECTRIC  L  FLAMENOL   SI 53076 105C

Comment: Where on this planet are you @Paul?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel   USA.  What's the issue?

Comment: @paul -- I suspect you have the wrong wire for the job...

Comment: How did you figure out that the old wire was 12AWG by the way?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The label on the spool shows that the wire is 12 gage.  It also shows CD 12R.  I do not know what that means.

Comment: @paul -- no, the *wire you are replacing* i.e. the messed-up wire in the oven

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Sorry, I miss-read your comment.  The oven wire is 16AWG per the wiring diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a dual-rated (TFFN/AWM) wire suitable for 105°C

The bad news is you have the wrong wire (UL listed wires are marked, and your replacement wire *isn't*, so it's no good).  The good news is that we know two things here:

1. This wire is replacing wire *within an appliance*, so UL-listed Appliance Wiring Material (AWM) is the correct family of things to use
2. We have the old wire's temperature rating (105°C)

Thus, we can safely use a *dual-rated* 16AWG stranded wire (TFFN/AWM) that has a 105°C rating when used in an AWM application -- most TFFN sold today will be of the dual-rated type, but double-check the printing on the wire when you're buying it to make sure.

Comment: This is correct if it requires 12AWG wire. But how do you know that is the right size wire?

Comment: @manassehkatz -- yeah, I was kind of going off him buying the right size wire -- following up in the comments :)

Comment: I did look first for a manual, but I couldn't find one quickly/easily to check a parts diagram. I think this is a pre-internet oven.

Comment: @manassehkatz -- The oven was installed in 1981 when the house was built.