# Wire Melts at Connector to Broil Element on Electric Oven

Tags: electrical, oven

I have a Hotpoint RK38T electric oven with a 3410 W broil element and 16 awg 125 C wire connection to one side of the element.

The wire to the broil element melted at the connector. See image of connector and wire.

The wire melted at the same point in March 2018, after 36 years of use. See image of connector.  I could not find a duplicate of the original connector.   I replaced the connector with a high-temperature ring connector.

What caused the wire to get hot enough to melt?  How do I prevent this from happening again?

The oven is the one in:

[Electric oven: Bake and Broil not Working](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136024/electric-oven-bake-and-broil-not-working)

[electric oven bake element gets warm but does not get hot](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132489/electric-oven-bake-element-gets-warm-but-does-not-get-hot)

[image: connector and wire]

[image: original connector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a poor connection wire to connector or connector to element, either causes an increase in resistance and therefore heating.

It may be worth replacing that wire either from its source or cutting it back until you get to clean undamaged wire with a good connection to a newcterminal and cleaning the element connection surface.

Comment: Thanks.  Would there be any tell-tale signs on the connector or element surface to indicate a poor connection at the wire to connector or connector to element surface?  The connector is discolored on the crimp section.  Also, I used a 22-18 connector with the 16 gauge wire.   Could the smaller connector add significant resistance?