# What Cause Hum from Electric Oven after Replacing Wire and Ring Connector to Broil Element?

Tags: electrical, oven

What Cause Hum from Electric Oven after Replacing Wire and Ring Connector to Broil Element?

After the wire melted at the connector to the broil element, I replaced the 16 gauge wire and 22-18 high-temperature ring connector with 14 gauge wire and a 16-14 high-temperature ring connector.  Now there is a low-volume hum from the oven when the broiler is on, no hum in bake mode.  The broiler works and the wire and connectors appear OK.

What causes the hum?  How do I fix it?  Is it safe to use the broiler while it hums?

The oven is the one in:

[Wire Melts at Connector to Broil Element on Electric Oven](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/169109/wire-melts-at-connector-to-broil-element-on-electric-oven)

[Electric oven: Bake and Broil not Working](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136024/electric-oven-bake-and-broil-not-working)

[electric oven bake element gets warm but does not get hot](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132489/electric-oven-bake-element-gets-warm-but-does-not-get-hot)

Answer (score 1):

Hums usually occur when the items or conductors you replaced or repaired are not remounted properly and vibrate while activated. Try checking out all of your connections and see if everything is mounted tight enough.

Good luck